# Can't Get Fast.ai fastpages GitHub To Display

Tags: github-pages, fast-ai

I'm trying to set up github-pages for fast.ai using the fastpages template cited in Appendix A of ["Deep Learning for Coders with fastai & PyTorch"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1492045527).  I keep getting a 404 when the URL of the repo.

There's a simpler version of the blog template without Jupyter notebook pages support.  I have no problem bringing it to life.

I've made the Gemfile.lock and _config.yml files similar, differing only in the GitHub repo details, but no joy.

Has anyone has success getting the fastpages template to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a step.

I re-read the instructions carefully and realized that there was a pull request created.

I had to create public and private keys to update on commits.

I committed the pull request and waited a minute.  Once I did that the page came up.